# API powershell request with error handling

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Purpose of code:
To make a post request to a server via API

Reason I'm here:
When I make the post request it returns

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod @restpostParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

My question for the community:
The 404 error actually is in error because the POST request works and sends the data I need it to send. I want a way to catch this error and have the script continue on. I've been looking into try and catch blocks with PS, however I'm just not sure how to get started with them. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you catch an exception, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Looks like you're running PowerShell 7, in that case just try this: `Invoke-RestMethod @restpostParams -SkipHttpErrorCheck`